# How to redirect to url if logged in successful using codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, model, controller

I am enable enable_query_strings and want to redirect url when user login successful through redirect() method.

Url look like this:

```
http://localhost/DemoTest/index.php?c=admin_controller&m=login&d=backend
```

config file setting:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING';
$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

admin_controller Code:

```
    function login() {
            $data['page_title'] = "Admin Login";
            if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
                $this->load->library('form_validation');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', "Username", "trim|required");
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', "Password", "trim|required");
                if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
                    $this->index();
                } else {
                    $result = $this->admin_model->check_login();
                    if ($result) {
                        $user_data = array(
                            'username' => $_POST['username'],
                            'login' => TRUE,
                        );
                        $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);
                        site_url('m=admin_controller&t=dashboard&s=backend');

     //Here i can call redirect() function to redirect this url 
http://localhost/DemoSite/index.php?c=admin_controller&m=dashboard&d=backend

                    } else {
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('login_failed', 'The login info you entered is invalid');
                    }
                }
            }
            $this->load->view('backend/templates/header_assets.php', $data);
            $this->load->view('backend/login');
        }
```

Comment: so whats the problem here? you are not able to redirect to this page "http://localhost/DemoSite/index.php?c=admin_controller&m=dashboard&d=backend"

Comment: Have you tried `redirect('index.php?c=admin_controller&m=dashboard&d=backend')` or `redirect(c=admin_controller&m=dashboard&d=backend)`

Comment: Make sure you have autoloaded url helper

Comment: Use header("location:http://localhost/DemoSite/index.php?c=admin_controller&m=dashboard&d=backend");

Comment: Thanks @wolfgang1983, it's working.

Comment: Read user guide more http://www.codeigniter.com/docs

Answer (score 0):

After a login successfully done page redirected using `redirect()`, see below example:

```
redirect('Login', 'refresh');
```

you just paste this line and replace login to your controller name and method